# Display the saved file on the webbrowser

Tags: javascript, php, c++, c

I have written a code to capture the packets on the interface using libpcap library  and saved in the file i need to display it on the web browser .can any one suggest how to display the saved file on the browser .

Comment: Why do you think the browser is able to display the file? (other than displaying the pure content, ie. unreadable "nonsense")

Comment: `system("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\" display.txt");`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Wireshark instead for your purpose. Why the browser? I dont think your browser can interpret pcap files.

However, there does exist a paid service called CloudShark which basically allows you to upload your pcap files to their server and perform analysis using your browser as the Interface.

More at:
https://appliance.cloudshark.org/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @pNre i added a solution, after reading your comment. Hope its enough. However, i will follow your suggestion in the future :)